# "Show Details" vs "See details"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I have this table, which has a button to go to the "Details page" of that transaction.

What would be more natural or appropriate for the button's label?

- See Details
- See Detail
- Show Details
- Other?

[image]

Comment: I would be inclined to refer to you to http://ux.stackexchange.com for advice on how to lay out your table and its controls....

Comment: I've thought of posting there, because I participate in that community, but I think it's more an English word-choice than an usability case. I would post this in UX if you tell me for example, that there are 3 equivalent options at a language level. I'm deleting the "details" option, because that makes a mix between word-use and usability.

Comment: From a language perspective, none of your options would jump out at me as poorly worded. I could tell you my personal preference from a UI perspective, but I think the UX folks would be able to offer more insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect a button to execute my command, not tell me what to do - which means it's "*Show* Details", not "*See* Details". 
And it should be plural, because I'd expect a certain amount of information.

Comment: For sure "Show details" is the way to go. I think you could just simplify it to "Details" and it would be fine. At the end of the day, people who are browsing this table would not notice this minor detail ;)